# Implementation of permissions and groups as in Azure DevOps

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, .net-5

I am looking for information on whether it is possible to implement permissions and groups as in Azure DevOps using ASP.NET Core Identity.

In DevOps they use Azure AD, but is it possible to do a similar system in ASP.NET Core Identity with users and claims stored in the local database?

Is there any example project with this permission system?

[image]

Comment: It seems your issue is not related to DevOps, did you mean you want to implement a similar system to DevOps permission setting?